# Loop through grid columns in runtime in AX 2012

Tags: grid, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to loop through columns(fields) in grid control in AX 2012 form. I have this logic to loop through fields :

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
    SysDictTable    dictTable = new SysDictTable(tableNum(PurchLine));
    SysDictField    dictField;
    TreeNode        treeNode;
    FieldId         fieldId = dictTable.fieldNext(0);

    while (fieldId)
    {
        dictField = dictTable.fieldObject(fieldId);

        if (dictField.isSql() && !dictField.isSystem())
        {
            treeNode = dictField.treeNode();
            info(strFmt("%1 | %2 | %3",
                dictField.name(),                                               // Field name
                treeNode.AOTgetProperty("Label"),                               // Label id
                SysLabel::labelId2String(treeNode.AOTgetProperty("Label"))));   // Label string
        }

        fieldId = dictTable.fieldNext(fieldId);
    }
}
```

This loop through table, I need similar logic to loop through grid fields but in RUNTIME.
For example if grid data source has 5 columns and 3 are removed in UI, i want to loop just through these 2 that are left in the grid.
So my question is how to get grid fields in runtime( not from datasource table) ?

Answer (score 2):

The below assumes your grid is named "GridOverview". You call it like:

`::outputGridControls(element)` where `element` is your form.

```
public static void outputGridControls(FormRun _formRun)
{
    int                     i;
    FormGridControl         formGridControl;
    FormControl             formControl;

    formGridControl = _formRun.control(_formRun.controlId(identifierStr(GridOverview)));
    
    if (formGridControl)
    {
        for (i=1; i<=formGridControl.controlCount(); i++)
        {
            formControl = formGridControl.controlNum(i);
            
            if (formControl && formControl.visible())
            {
                info(strFmt("%1 (%2)", formControl.name(), formControl.labelText()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you're doing above is reflecting on the AOT table, but you need to be looking at the `FormRun` and not the actual table or even the `DataSource`.